# Adding tinymce to Custom Field boxes on Category edit page

Tags: categories, custom-field, tinymce

I've managed to add the required custom fields to my category edit page (the code is below). All I'd like to do it have the textareas #Category_Extras_Features and #Category_Extras_Applications to have a tinymce editor on them?

```
    // Add custom fields to category edit pages
// the option name
define('Category_Extras', 'Category_Extras_option');

// your fields (the form)
add_filter('edit_category_form', 'Category_Extras');
function Category_Extras($tag) {
    $tag_extra_fields = get_option(Category_Extras);

    ?>

<table class="form-table">
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="Category_Extras_Features">Category Features</label></th>
            <td><textarea style="width: 97%;" cols="50" rows="5" name="Category_Extras_Features" id="Category_Extras_Features"><?php  echo $tag_extra_fields[$tag->term_id]['Category_Extras_Features']; ?></textarea>

            <p class="description">This isn't applicable to all categories but allows additional information to be displayed on a category page.</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="Category_Extras_Applications">Category Applications</label></th>
            <td><textarea style="width: 97%;" cols="50" rows="5" name="Category_Extras_Applications" id="Category_Extras_Applications"><?php  echo $tag_extra_fields[$tag->term_id]['Category_Extras_Applications']; ?></textarea>
            <p class="description">This isn't applicable to all categories but allows additional information to be displayed on a category page.</p></td>
        </tr>
</table>



    <?php
}


// when the form gets submitted, and the category gets updated (in your case the option will get updated with the values of your custom fields above
add_filter('edited_terms', 'update_Category_Extras');
function update_Category_Extras($term_id) {
  if($_POST['taxonomy'] == 'category'):
    $tag_extra_fields = get_option(Category_Extras);
    $tag_extra_fields[$term_id]['Category_Extras_Features'] = strip_tags($_POST['Category_Extras_Features']);
    $tag_extra_fields[$term_id]['Category_Extras_Applications'] = strip_tags($_POST['Category_Extras_Applications']);
    update_option(Category_Extras, $tag_extra_fields);
  endif;
}


// when a category is removed
add_filter('deleted_term_taxonomy', 'remove_Category_Extras');
function remove_Category_Extras($term_id) {
  if($_POST['taxonomy'] == 'category'):
    $tag_extra_fields = get_option(Category_Extras);
    unset($tag_extra_fields[$term_id]);
    update_option(Category_Extras, $tag_extra_fields);
  endif;
}
```

Is this possible, and if so anyone know how to do this?

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial [**TinyMCE in WordPress Plugins**](http://www.keighl.com/2010/01/tinymce-in-wordpress-plugins/)  and you'll get there.

Comment: Link returns a 404.